# Jetpack Compose set image height before loading remote image

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have a list of dynamically sized images. I already know the size of the images in pixels. I would like to place a placeholder of the same remote image dimension before the image is loaded just so that while scrolling in the LazyColumn the list doesn't jump up and down

Given the following code, which uses Coil:

```
@Composable
fun CloudImage(
  url: String,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  imageHeight: Int // I also got the image width... but I am using ContentScale = Fit
) {
  AsyncImage(
    model = url,
    modifier = modifier
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    contentDescription = null
  )
}
```

How do I automatically fill the height in my LazyColumn item so there's no more jank while the image is being loaded?

I thought about converting the image height from pixels to dp but since I am using ContentScale.Fit this doesn't make sense

Comment: If you know image width and height why don't you set Modifier.size(imageWidthInDp, ImageHeightInDp) to AsyncImage?

Comment: @Thracian because I’m using content scale fit, meaning I can’t just convert height to dp and set that as height

Comment: It's possible to calculate the dimensions of an image even without setting it but it's little bit complicated. If anyone doesn't come up with answer you can accept you can check [here](https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Image-Cropper/blob/master/imagecropper/src/main/java/com/smarttoolfactory/imagecropper/ImageWithConstraints.kt) This is an Image that returns width and height of image drawn with any ContentScale also returns which region of ImageBitmap is drawn. With some tweaks you would be able to calculate area without imageBitmap since you know dimensions

Comment: @Thracian that links seems no longer available, returns 404 :(

Comment: @BuddyChrist here you go. This is the link for the image library that uses Composable and draw area to implement other features. https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Compose-Image

Comment: Have you, by any chance, found a solution? If you have, could you post an answer?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image width, then you could calculate the aspect ratio and use that in a modifier.

This is what I've done for a vertical column of full width images that I know the aspect ratio of.

```
Box(Modifier.fillMaxWidth().aspectRatio(aspectRatio)) {
  AsyncImage(
    model = url,
    contentDescription = null,
    placeholder = ColorPainter(Color.Gray)
  )
}
```

Perhaps this could be a solution:

```
@Composable
fun CloudImage(
  url: String,
  modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
  aspectRatio: Float, // <-- passing the aspect ratio
) {
  AsyncImage(
    model = url,
    modifier = modifier.aspectRatio(aspectRatio)
    contentScale = ContentScale.Fit,
    contentDescription = null
  )
}
```